# Having 3 Entities, get the third Entity as a result, based on the number of relations(count) of the other 2 Entities

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have 3 Entities, Type, Item, Owner

Owner

```
id name
1   owner1
2   owner2
3   owner3
```

An Owner can have multiple Items

```
Item

id   name  owner_id
1   item1  1
2   item2  1
3   item3  1 
4   item4  3
5   item5  2

Type 

id name
1  alpha 
2  beta
```

There is a Many to Many relationship between Item and Type. An Item can have multiple Type, and a Type can have multiple Item

```
Item_Type

id item_id type_id

1   1       1
2   1       2 
3   3       1
4   4       1
```

Giving a Type by name, I need to get all Owners which have Item of that Type, ordered by the number of Item per Type.

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.

So I start with:

```
SELECT Type.name, Item_Type.item_id from Type WHERE Type.name = 'my_var' INNER JOIN Item_Type ON Type.id = Item_Type.type_id
```

So I need to count Item per Type, and after get the Owners DISTINCT ordered by count.

I don't know how to approach this order by count.

***Expected - Example:***

So, if for Type I select the `name` : 'alpha' which corresponds to the `id 1`

The `item_id` corresponding to `Type` with `id 1` are: `1,3,4`

The Item(s) with id `1,3` corresponding `owner_id` is 1 (count=2).
The Item with id `4` corresponding `owner_id` is 3 (count=1).

So the result, (in order) will be `owner1, owner3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fdda013c98721aaec9daffbb687adf7)**

```
select d.name as ownername,count(distinct c.name) as itemcount from 
Item_Type a 
inner join Types b on a.type_id=b.id
inner join Item c on a.item_id=c.id
inner join Owner d on c.owner_id=d.id
group by d.name
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will fetch your desired results. It finds all the items that each owner owns, then filters them by item type to only include those of type `alpha`, and then does a `COUNT` of the number of items the owner has and sorts the results by that value descending:

```
SELECT t.name, o.name, COUNT(i.id) AS num_type
FROM Owner o
JOIN Item i ON i.owner_id = o.id
JOIN Item_Type it ON it.item_id = i.id
JOIN Type t ON t.id = it.type_id
WHERE t.name = 'alpha'
GROUP BY t.name, o.name
ORDER BY num_type DESC
```

Output:

```
name    name    num_type
alpha   owner1  2
alpha   owner3  1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d3144dc4f65a4eda35f2c7ac7316ad35)